# Как обратиться к переменной с id в имени? JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, есть такой код:

```
var colors1234 = {
  qwe: qweq
},
    colors1212 = {
  qwe: qweq
};


console.log(colors/*id*/);
```

Можно ли как-то обратится к такой переменной, если id динамическое?

Comment: У вас невалидный javascript

Comment: Поправил, спасибо

Comment: Я использую `eval("colors"+id)`

Comment: @nick_n_a а если вместо id прилетит что то вроде `=true;window.location.href='evil.com'` ? eval небезопасен.

Comment: @Darth, _eval небезопасен_ - только если в него прилетает не доверенная строка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

За счёт того, что ваша переменная лежит в глобальной области видимости, можно использовать [скобочную нотацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)  -

```js
var colors1234 = {
  qwe: 'qweq1234'
},
    colors1212 = {
  qwe: 'qweq1212'
};

const id = 1234;
console.log(window[`colors${id}`]);
```

Но лучше вместо пачки переменных формата имя+id сделать такой объект -

```
имя{
    id1: ...value...
    id2: ...value...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Comment: @Виктор Обращайтесь) И обратите внимание на вторую часть ответа. Если бы ваша переменная лежала, к примеру, в замыкании - её так просто достать было бы нельзя.

Comment: Вы показали обратные кавычки, это равнозначно `window['colors'+id]`?

Comment: Да, это называется [шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)