# Подскажите как вызвать метод обьекта используя переменную?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

У меня создаются обьекты в имени которых есть дата.

```
post_05_07_2017.titlePost
```

Мне нужно чтоб дата вставлялась с переменной.

Пробовал вот так

```
 post_+dataNow+.titlePost
```

ругается на точку

а если имя вот такое??

```
dataB.post_05_07_2017.titlePost
```

Comment: @Grundy Поспешишь - людей насмешишь. В данном случае не факт, что такой метод вообще применим

Comment: @Darth, такой метод всегда применим :-)

Comment: @Grundy `(function(){ let a_1 = 1; let index = 1;     /*как достать a_+index?*/  }())`
`

Comment: Тут лучше подойдет мой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678189/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81-id-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-js

Comment: @Darth, `return a_1` :P Не, твой ответ не подойдет, так как в твоем же примере переменная локальная. здесь только `eval`

Comment: _У меня создаются объекты в имени которых есть дата._ - как именно они создаются и где?

Comment: а если имя вот такое??

dataB.post_05_07_2017.titlePost

Comment: @Grundy в моем ответе показано, как избежать такой проблемы вообще

Comment: @Darth :-D ну да, использовать скобочную нотацию и объект

Comment: @Darth, `dataB.post_05_07_2017.titlePost` - похоже все-таки дубликат верен :-)

Comment: просто меняй точки на квадратные скобки, внутри которых должна быть строка: `dataB['post_05_07_2017']['titlePost']` или `dataB['post_05_07_2017'].titlePost`

Comment: спасибо) работает